# How to define expensive operation in sql

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to apprehend the idea of expensive. Here's an example based on my understanding.If I want to find the id of all users aged above 18 select * from table where age > 18 select * is then expensive as I only wanted id.
Is expensive a negative word so it should always be avoided?

Comment: Without more context I would guess "expensive" could mean a query that consumes a lot of resources of the database. Can you add context? Where did you read that?

Comment: @TheImpaler sorry I can't really find the original but I think you are right, expensive means time consuming to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `expensive` and `cheap` are often use to measure if some execution plan is better then an other. I guess it is based on the fact that the engine is calculating the `cost` of possible execution plans and choosing the `cheaper` one.

For example, in `posgresql` (but similar in others RDMBs) we [have](https://scalegrid.io/blog/postgres-explain-cost/):

> The costs are in an arbitrary unit. A common misunderstanding is that
> they are in milliseconds or some other unit of time, but that’s not
> the case.
>
> The cost units are anchored (by default) to a single sequential page
> read costing 1.0 units (seq_page_cost). Each row processed adds 0.01
> (cpu_tuple_cost), and each non-sequential page read adds 4.0
> (random_page_cost).

So, based on your operators, the engine is determining the cost of your query and we can say that is better to avoid expensive operations. Some of the SQL performance tuning may include moving some of the business logic in the application in order to avoid heavy (not fast enough) operations.